# Inspect unit status for user-units with systemctl as root

Tags: linux, systemd

I've created a user unit (slice) and started it. With:

```
cytrinox@pollux$ systemctl status --user --full firefox-limits.slice
● firefox-limits.slice - Firefox Slice
   Loaded: loaded (/home/cytrinox/.config/systemd/user/firefox-limits.slice; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active since Sun 2018-11-25 00:09:14 CET; 37min ago
   CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/firefox.slice/firefox-limits.slice
           └─run-r791a1fc1147748059accf82ecded4c56.scope
             ├─5291 /home/cytrinox/bin/Firefox/firefox
             ├─5451 /home/cytrinox/bin/Firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 1 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 1 -prefMapSize 452779 -schedulerPre
             ├─5500 /home/cytrinox/bin/Firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 2 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 1 -prefMapSize 452779 -schedulerPre
             ├─5517 /home/cytrinox/bin/Firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 3 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 1 -prefMapSize 452779 -schedulerPre
             ├─5539 /home/cytrinox/bin/Firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 4 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 1 -prefMapSize 452779 -schedulerPre
             └─5562 /home/cytrinox/bin/Firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 5 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 1 -prefMapSize 452779 -schedulerPre

Nov 25 00:09:14 pollux systemd[858]: Created slice Firefox Slice.
```

I can inspect the current status.

But as, root, how can I get the status for this user unit?

```
root@pollux:/etc/systemd/system# systemctl status --full firefox-limits.slice
● firefox-limits.slice
   Loaded: loaded
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, it's not possible to access the units running under the systemd unit manager while running as root...

It is *almost* possible to do so, by running `systemctl --user status` as root while setting the `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` environment variable to point to `/run/user/<uid>` (see [the relevant code in `bus_connect_user_systemd()`](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v239/src/shared/bus-util.c#L602)), but unfortunately this is not enough:

```
# XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000 systemctl --user status
Failed to connect to bus: Operation not permitted
```

The problem is that, after connecting to the user manager, systemd checks that the uid running `systemctl` matches the one that owns the socket to the manager (see [the relevant code in `bus_check_peercred()`](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v239/src/shared/bus-util.c#L555)).

So your best choice is to just use `su` to become the user in order to check the status of the unit. Furthermore, when using `su`, you still need to set `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`, since otherwise `systemctl` might be unable to find the socket to the manager:

```
# su cytrinox -c 'XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$UID systemctl --user status'
```

(Or the appropriate `systemctl status` command you want for your Firefox slice unit...)

Comment: See also: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/11000

Comment: systemd 248 (released March 2021) introduced support https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/654846/9360  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/730141/9360