# Stop systemd user services as root user

Tags: systemd, root

I have a systemd `A@.service` that every user on the server can start with `systemd --user start A@1.service`.

As root I would like to stop that service for all users when we do maintenance.

I haven't found a way in systemd man, not even via Conflict. Is there a way to stop user services as root?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As root, systemd supports actions on user services using a combination of the `--user` and `--machine` flags ...

e.g.

```
systemctl --user --machine=<user>@.host <command> <service>
```

or, it can be shortened to (on localhost)

```
systemctl --user --machine=<user>@ <command> <service>
```

i.e.

```
systemctl --user --machine=jtingiris@ stop a-user.service
```

That is documented in [`man 1 systemctl`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#-M) ...

> `-M`, `--machine=`
>
> Execute operation on a local container. Specify a container
> name to connect to, optionally prefixed by a user name to
> connect as and a separating "`@`" character. If the special
> string "`.host`" is used in place of the container name, a
> connection to the local system is made (which is useful to
> connect to a specific user's user bus: "`--user --machine=lennart@.host`"). If the "`@`" syntax is not used, the
> connection is made as root user. If the "`@`" syntax is used
> either the left hand side or the right hand side may be
> omitted (but not both) in which case the local user name and
> "`.host`" are implied.

Comment: I believe, based on [this comment](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/11216#issuecomment-842984271) you have to be on systemd >= 248. For older versions you can try `runuser` from answer by @Dave

Answer (score 1):

@Joseph Tingiris post did not work for me.
I kept getting "Cannot access user instance remotely."

Workaround was to use `runuser` as root:

```
runuser -l userNameHere -c 'systemctl --user stop user-service.service'
```

**EDIT**: I forgot to mention that this will also work with the following:

```
su - userNameHere -c 'systemctl --user stop user-service.service'
```

But all this only works if the user is ACTUALLY logged in (via direct terminal, GUI, or SSH.)