# Run systemctl --user commands as root

Tags: systemd, users, d-bus

I need root to be able to manage `systemctl --user` units.

Right now I have `user1` set up with systemd user units. If the user logs in directly via terminal, GUI, or SSH, they are able to to run all `systemctl --user` commands.

While the user is still logged in, I can run the following as root and perform all `systemctl --user` commands at that user with no problem:

```
su - user1 -c "systemctl --user status myunit.service"
```

However if the user logs off, then no one can run `systemctl --user` commands as that user, not even root. I will continue to get

```
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
```

Even if I `sudo - user1` as root, that is not good enough, will get the same error. The user literally needs to login to manage that user's units.

Apparently this is a known "issue" (quotes as the system is running as designed).

**Note:** I tried setting the `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` environment varialbe in `user1`'s `bashrc`, but that does not help.

Another user seems to have found a workaround, but it does not work. Looks like the developers did not approve of his [idea](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/483948/inspect-unit-status-for-user-units-with-systemctl-as-root).

The only work around I found is literally ssh into the user account to run commands like this after auth with public keys:

```
ssh user1@localhost -f 'systemctl --user status myunit.service'
```

I am looking for a workaround that does not require a SSH connection. I need root to be able to manage a systemd user unit while that user is not logged in. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I don't know whether that helps you, but your problem seems... unusual. Are you sure you don't just want to run a service as a user? Running a user service as root rings all my security problem alarm bells, and sounds like an architectural backwards approach ;)

Comment: @MarcusMüller I am curious what security issues you see in root being able to run a user service. Can you elaborate more? Unrelated, its a requirement of the project. The project uses a scripted installer to deploy all packages for a user and `systemctl --service`. The script needs to run as root.

Comment: if it installs all things as a user, why would it need to run as root?

Comment: Good question, the installer does other actions that require root permissions, so the installer needs to run as root.

Comment: hm, so why not a root-installed systemd .service that specifies that the service is to be run as user1?

Comment: Because user1 needs to be able to control the service as well, systemctl start, stop, restart, etc.

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/552922/315749

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured out a very clean way of doing this that does not involve having the user actually logged in. Needed to enable linger with loginctl for the user as root.

`loginctl enable-linger user1`

Then you can check status with

`loginctl user-status user1`

This should list all processes the user is running from their systemd process.
Now I can run, as root without the user actually being logged in:

`runuser -l user1 -c 'systemctl --user status myunit.service'`

Comment: Support for running `systemctl --user` commands as root was added to __systemd 248__. See `-M` option.

Comment: The systemctl -M switch is only available starting with RHEL9. RHEL8 is still at version 239. You should have specified it.

Answer (score 9):

**systemd 248** (released March 2021) introduced support for the syntax `-M username@` for specifying another user.

```
$ sudo systemctl --user -M user1@ status myunit.service
```

Reference: The new feature listed in the file [NEWS](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/28795f2c138203fb700fc394f0937708af886116/NEWS#LL2820C10-L2820C10)

(There is no need to run `loginctl enable-linger user1` for this solution to work)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `su` or `sudo`, but use `machinectl` instead which will give you a proper user-session and context.

You can either just drop in a shell, just as you're used to from `su`/`sudo`:

```
machinectl shell root@.host
```

…and execute whatever you want to in the given user's context, or you can pass the cmd to be executed as an additional argument, e.g.:

```
machinectl shell root@.host $(which bash) -c "systemctl --user status myunit.service"
```

Make sure not to nest $(which bash) -c in quotes.

Comment: This does not work when trying to pass a command via bash. Tried the following as a simple test:
`machinectl shell user1@.host "/bin/bash -c 'whoami'"`. I get no output and the session terminates. Output in /var/log/messages is 
"container-shell@8.service: Executable /bin/bash -c 'whoami' missing, skipping: No such file or directory" Is there some special way to send commands I am unaware of?

Comment: Got it working! syntax should actually be `machinectl shell user1@.host /bin/bash -c "whoami"` Dont next /bin/bash in quotes.

Comment: I should add this command will hang if `systemctl --user daemon-reload` is run.

Comment: @Dave `$(which bash)` should be wrapped in double quotes to prevent word splitting and globbing, though it's really unlikely to be an issue. Your example, `machinectl shell user1@.host /bin/bash -c whoami`, would be fine even with no quotes at all, because the command string (what follows `-c`) is a single word. In general, you'd want the command string wrapped in double quotes if expansions are meant to happen in the current shell (where `machinectl` runs) and in single quotes if expansions are meant to happen in the shell invoked by `machinectl`.